# Pyspark function for matching strings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, string-matching

I have two tables

Table 1: (comment_df)

```
| Date | Comment | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| 20/01/2020 | Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday. |
| 20/01/2020 | Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday. |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row. |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed. |
```

Table 2: (code_df)

```
| Tag | Comment | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| EURO | Euro Account to HSBC |
| Natwest | Euro Account to Natwest |
| AMEX | AMEX payment |
```

The desired table is

```
| Date | Comment | Tag |
|:---- |:------:| ----:|
| 20/01/2020 | Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday. | EURO |
| 20/01/2020 | Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday. | Natwest |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row. | AMEX | 
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed. | |
```

I can probably do with using .contains or matcher(nlp.vocab?) for a few categories. But I have over 30 categories and the list can grow over time. So I was hoping for a function using pyspark that can do this elegantly.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A `left join` is probably appropriate:

```
code_df = code_df.withColumnRenamed('Comment', 'Commentcode')

result = comment_df.join(code_df, comment_df.Comment.contains(code_df.Commentcode), 'left').drop('Commentcode')

result.show(truncate=False)
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|Date      |Comment                                                              |Tag    |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|20/01/2020|Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday.           |EURO   |
|20/01/2020|Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday.|Natwest|
|21/01/2020|AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row.        |AMEX   |
|21/01/2020|AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed.                             |null   |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: the challenge I have come across is multiple tags occurring if more than one keyword is matched and I want it to stop at the first keyword itself. Any suggestions on resolving this?